# Zyxel router VMG 3313-B10A three different ip addresses?

Tags: router, ip, address

Is it possible for a router to have 3 different ip addresses?

1. internal ip address 192.168.1.1
2. ip address assigned to router 100.83.x.x
3. public ip or isp address ( when i google what is my ip ) it gives me something else.

The ARP Routing Table shows the following
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bYHA.jpg)

How come I have 3 addresses? Is my traffic being re-routed some place else?

Comment: 100.83.0.1 isn’t a public IP address.

Comment: You "have" 3 addresses, but they serve different purposes. I guess the address assigned to the router is 10.83.x.x. In that case, your traffic (from 192.168.1.1) is  being NATted (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation for details) and the public IP address is the one your ISP uses to connect to the Internet. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have both a private IP address and a Public IP address. When you request a webpage, packets can't reach your computer using your private IP address. So your router has also a public IP address (what you got when you googled) and that is translated using network address translation (NAT). That means when you wan't visit something outside your LAN then you need your public IP address.

Carrier grade NAT (CGN) is a process to ensure that the routing process and IP addresses unique and avoid confpict. And CGN uses Shared address space. And 100.83.x.x is used by shared address space.